# Simulating an actual left click using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to input a starting and end date. They do appear but the website does not recognize them unless I actually physically use my mouse and click into the text box. I've tried start_date.click() and that does not work either. Is there anyway to simulate a physical left click so that the cursor is blinking inside the text box? This seems to be the only way.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#Website excluded on purpose

posting_date = "2015-01-05"
closing_date = "2015-01-07"

#input posting date
start_date = driver.find_element_by_name("dnf_class_values[job][job_start]")
start_date.send_keys(posting_date)

#input end date
end_date = driver.find_element_by_name("dnf_class_values[job][job_end]")
end_date.send_keys(closing_date + Keys.RETURN)
```

Heres a picture of the error I'm getting and the element corresponding to the start_date variable

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIuMr.jpg)

Comment: what do you mean of not recognize? could you show that part of html content?

Comment: How is it not working.  Is there an error?  Does nothing happen at all?  If there is an error, could you please post it in your question?  And as Anzel asked, could you please show the HTML you are attempting to interact with?

Comment: updated with link of html and errors shown